# Is my DDR3 RAM working to its maximum potential?

Tags: memory

I have an old (2010) Netbook, Samsung N150Plus, which I thought I might be able to upgrade the memory to get a bit more out of it. Running Linux Mint on it, and `lshw` reports...

> 2GiB SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)

...whereas when I look at the memory stick inside it's labelled as "Kingston KVR1066D3S7/2G", which appears to be 2GB of 1066Mhz DDR3 and seems to have the correct footprint for DDR3.

The processor is reported by `lshw` as...

> Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N550   @ 1.50GHz

If it is DDR3 how can I be sure that the processor is actually using the the RAM correctly (at DDR3 rates), and is there anything I can do to optimise.

edit: updated information above and images added: 
[Samsung N150Plus back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgHwM.jpg),
[RAM in Samsung N150Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O8KM.jpg)

Comment: `lshw` relies on DMI and as such is super inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks, is there something more accurate that I can use?

Comment: @Dan_7378439012 Remove the module and look at the label.  Update your question with details from the label.  Additionally, edit your question, and provide which cpu you have exactly.  Please don’t submit information in a comment

Comment: Well, CPU-Z is as accurate as it gets. However, it’s a Windows application. I’m not aware of an equivalent solution for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

[Samsung's website](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/laptops/NP-N150-JA01US-specs) says your netbook uses DDR2 RAM; [Crucial's memory upgrade finder](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Samsung/n150-plus) concurs.  [DDR3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM) memory started appearing in late 2007 and took several years to reach low-end devices.  Given all that, and since DDR3 is not backwards-compatible, it's highly likely that the memory module in your computer is mislabeled DDR2.

(Incidentally, memory speed is about the last thing you should worry about for computer performance.  A good rule of thumb is that doubling your memory speed will result in an overall 5% increase in performance.)